# How to create subdirectories while saving Python files on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, import, package

I'm learning Python using a book that uses Window's based examples and they use these as examples (the comments are the filenames):

```
# dir1\__init__.py
print('dir1 init')
x = 1

# dir1\dir2\__init__.py
print('dir1 init')
y = 2

# dir1\dir2\mod.py
print('in mod.py')
z = 3
```

Now using IDLE, it attempts to import the files using:

```
import dir1.dir2.mod
```

Which will display:

```
dir1 init
dir2 init
in mod.py
```

When I attempt to do this on IDLE on my Mac it comes up with an error saying there is no module named `dir1`.
The point of the exercise is to package imports but I don't if I'm formatting the files incorrectly or importing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but your file structure should look like this in Finder:

[image]

which is:

```
dir1
|-- __init__.py
|-- dir2
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- mod.py
```

And you need to make sure that your working directory in IDLE is the directory where `dir1` is located. I don't think you can change that in IDLE, but you could do this to make it work:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/directory/where/dir1/is/stored')
```

Comment: When I save these files, should it create a new folder called dir1 and dir2? Or do I manually have to create them myself.  Python 3.6 exists in my applications folder and within that IDLE exists.  Should I create another folder within there or just save it in the 3.6 folder?

Comment: I would attach a picture but cannot in a comment unfortunately.

Comment: I wouldn't create a folder in the applications folder, I would create the folders `dir1` etc. in your documents folder and then use `sys` to make IDLE think that `dir1` is in de same directory. And yes, I think you need to make the folders and files manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the files are not in the same directory from where the IDLE is running or looking at.

Try to see where the IDLE is on your Mac, complete path. Once find that out may be try putting the files in the same place so that python can see those files.

As an experiment, I'd suggest, writing your scripts in an editor like VS Code. `cd` into the directory where you have saved the script. Run the script by `python` yourfilename.py and see what it says then. Personally, I have never used the IDLE but I have come across python not being able to find the file.

Comment: When I save these files, should it create a new folder called dir1 and dir2? Or do I manually have to create them myself. Python 3.6 exists in my applications folder and within that IDLE exists. Should I create another folder within there or just save it in the 3.6 folder?

Comment: You would have to make the directories yourself, I think. Try text editor route! Again, I am not too sure about IDLE. There, you will create your directories, place the files there, import them in another file (module) and then call that file.